# How to contribute to WordPress Core using Tortoise SVN?

Tags: core, core-modifications

I am expecting step by step guide how to submit patch using [Tortoise SVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/) because it is little bit unclear the [documentation](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/tutorials/working-with-patches/) for me.

For a example, it said,

> "**Open the folder**, and find the file you need to change. Open it in
>   your favorite plain-text editor. Note: Do not use a rich-text editor
>   such as Word or OpenOffice to edit the files."

What folder? I know that it means folder which has WordPress core files. But where should I get it? (From https://wordpress.org/download/ ???)

Then, when went to create a new ticket should I select "enhancement" as type?

Then how to upload patch?

Comment: https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/contribute/ Short version: You need to create ticket on Trac for the change you want to make and attach a patch. Then a core committer will need to accept and commit the change.

Comment: @JacobPeattie How to attach a patch

Comment: There's an attachment button on tickets in Trac.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find how to use subversion with WP and create a patch. https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Subversion